# How to use list comprehensions for two different lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

How I can use a list comprehension for this example?

```
l_words = list_word(domain)
words = list(l_words)
l_lines = [line for count, line in enumerate(open(file_found,"rb"))]
lines = list(l_lines)

# from here
for bline in lines:
    for word in words:
        try:
            aline = bline.decode()
            line = return_only_ascii(aline)
            if line == "\n":
                break
            if line.find(word) != -1:
                login += 1
# to here
```

I need to find 83 words in each .txt file, of course for each line I need to see if the word is in each line.

Comment: Since you don't seem to want to create a new list, a list comprehension is not appropriate. And you can't have a `try` block inside a list comprehension.

Comment: and if i use a list comprehension after try ?

Comment: Where is the ```except``` for the ```try```?

Comment: You can use a list comprehension before, after, or inside a `try` block.

Comment: Ok, but if i want only for now " without try", list comprehension ( for bline in lines:
    for word in words: ) how i can do it ?